# Sorting with Sort::Fields

Tags: perl, programming-languages

I'm trying to sort numerically in perl with [Sort::Fields](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aFields).

I see that it can sort with using 'n' but that seems to just sort by the first number

Say I have:

```
12
143
32
342
```

How can I get it to sort by size? Such as:

```
342
143
32
12
```

Note: I'm also sorting it on another field first: I'm trying to use:
print SORT fieldsort ',', [3, '1n'], @data;

Answer (score 6):

From the URL your provided,

> # numeric sort on column 1
>    print fieldsort ['1n'], @data;

This will sort numerically on the first column of each array ref in @data.

If this doesn't help, then include the code that's calling Sort::Fields subs

Comment: Oops! You are absolutely right and I had the right code. I made a stupid mistake and opened a file with >> so while I was making changes I never actually noticed because the changes were thousands of lines below :)